# Is it possible to communicate with AppServiceConnection and uwp in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

Is it possible to communicate with AppServiceConnection and uwp in WinForm? Error: does not contain the definition of "GetAwaiter", this is my code:
[image]
Thank you!

This is the code in WinForm:

```
private AppServiceConnection calculatorService;
    static Form1 mainForm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add the connection
        if (calculatorService == null)
        {
            calculatorService = new AppServiceConnection();
            calculatorService.AppServiceName = "com.yanscorp.appservicedemo.Values";
            calculatorService.PackageFamilyName = "c97887ad-1f75-4b48-9e3b-21b89c061715_6evysfdvxt248";

            var status = await calculatorService.OpenAsync();//A mistake here

            if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
            {
                string d = "Failed to connect";
                return;
            }
        }
var message = new ValueSet();
        message.Add("Request", "GetCallCount");
        AppServiceResponse response = await calculatorService.SendMessageAsync(message);//A mistake here
        string result = "";

        if (response.Status == AppServiceResponseStatus.Success)
        {
            result = response.Message["Response"] as string;
            // Get the data  that the service sent  to us.

                textBlock.Text = result;

        }
    }
```

Error:
错误  CS4036  “IAsyncOperation”不包含“GetAwaiter”的定义，并且找不到可接受类型为“IAsyncOperation”的第一个参数的扩展方法“GetAwaiter”(是否缺少针对“System”的 using 指令?)  WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (text, not image) and the exact details of the compiler error. Be sure to include the source code for the `OpenAsync` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are absolutely useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to redundantly repeat tag information in your title and text. The tag system works extremely well here, and doesn't need any help by repeating that information again and again. Add the tag and let it do it's job.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I upload this example? I can't find the place to upload.

Comment: Help, thank you very much

Comment: If I change the var status = await calculatorService.OpenAsync() to var status =  calculatorService.OpenAsync(), I will not report a mistake, but throw an exception in executing status.GetResults() and calculatorService.SendMessageAsync(): the method was invoked at the unexpected time.this is code:

Comment: var status =  calculatorService.OpenAsync();
                if (status.GetResults() == AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)//status.GetResults():Error: invoking a method at an unexpected time
                {
                    string d = "Failed to connect";
                    return;
                }

Comment: Please Help me ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to communicate with AppServiceConnection and uwp in WinForm

Yes. You could use App service in WinForm. Check [this article](https://aruntalkstech.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/calling-an-app-service-from-a-wpfwinforms-win32-app/) for more details.

> Error: does not contain the definition of "GetAwaiter"

You could access the Windows 10 APIs in WinForm by reference `winmd` file and `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`. It looks like you have already referenced `winmd` , but you may forget to reference `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` which you could find it in the directory  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5`.

Adding the reference of  `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` will resolve your issue. Details please reference [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have implemented WinForm and uwp to communicate through appService, but now there is a problem that the system will kill appService at any time, how to solve this problem

Comment: @Values, Answers on this thread should only answer the current issue on this thread. If you have resolved current issue please consider mark one as accepted that resolved your issue and open a new thread for your new issue or gave the new link about your issue. Thanks for understanding.